# Evaluating $\lim_{n\to \infty} n \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^n}{x+1} dx$

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals

Evaluating
$$L=\lim_{n\to \infty} n\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^n}{x+1} dx.$$
Let
$$I_n=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^n}{x+1} dx=\int_{0}^{1} x^{n-1}dx-I_{n-1}$$
When $n$ infinitely large $I_{n-1}\sim I_{n}$, then
$$I_n\sim \frac{1}{2n} \implies L= \frac{1}{2}.$$

The question is how else one can evaluate $L$?

Comment: Substitute $x=\mathrm{e}^{-t}$ with $0<t<+\infty$ and employ Watson's lemma.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589789)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{t} = 1$ for $t > 0$ and Dominance convergence:

\begin{align}
nI_n &\underset{t\,:=\,x^n}{=} \int_0^{1} \frac{\sqrt[n]{t}}{1 + \sqrt[n]{t}}\mathrm d t \underset{n\to \infty}{\to} \int_{0}^1 \frac12 \mathrm dt = \frac12
\end{align}

Answer (score 8):

Using an integration by parts, we have : \begin{aligned} n\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{x^{n}}{x+1}\,\mathrm{d}x}&=n\left[\frac{x^{n+1}}{\left(n+1\right)\left(x+1\right)}\right]_{0}^{1}+\frac{n}{n+1}\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{x^{n+1}}{\left(1+x\right)^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x}\\ &=\frac{n}{2\left(n+1\right)}+\frac{n}{n+1}\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{x^{n+1}}{\left(1+x\right)^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x} \end{aligned}

Since $ \left\lvert\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{x^{n+1}}{\left(1+x\right)^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x}\right\rvert\leq\int_{0}^{1}{x^{n+1}\,\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{1}{n+2}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$, then : $$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}{n\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{x^{n}}{x+1}}\,\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{1}{2} $$

Answer (score 4):

$I_n=n \displaystyle{\int_{0}^{1}}\dfrac{x^n}{x+1}dx$:

$\displaystyle \frac {1}{2} n \int_{0}^{1}  x^ndx < I_n <$
$\displaystyle \frac {1}{2} n \int_{0}^{1} x^{n-1} dx$;

$\displaystyle \frac {1}{2} \cdot \frac {n}{n + 1}
<I_n<$
$\displaystyle \frac {1}{2} \cdot \frac {n}{n}$;

Take the limit.

Used:

$\dfrac{x^n}{1+1}\le \dfrac{x^n}{x+1}\le \dfrac{x^n}{x+x}$ for $x \in 
(0,1]$;

Define a continuos function $f$:
$f(x)=0$ for $x=0$,
$f(x)= \dfrac {x^n}{x+x} = \displaystyle \frac {1}{2} x^{n-1}$ for $x>0$.

Then

$\dfrac{x^n}{1+1}\le \dfrac{x^n}{x+1}\le f(x)$ for $x \in [0,1]$

Answer (score 3):

Of course, $$nI_n = n \int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{x+1}dx \ge n \int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{2}dx = \frac{n}{2(n+1)} \to \frac{1}{2}$$ and for any $\varepsilon > 0$, $$ n I_n = n\int_0^{1-\varepsilon} \frac{x^n}{1+x}dx + n\int_{1-\varepsilon}^1 \frac{x^n}{1+x}dx $$ $$ \le n \int_0^{1-\varepsilon}(1-\varepsilon)^n dx + n \int_{1-\varepsilon}^1 \frac{x^n}{2-\varepsilon}dx $$ $$= n(1-\varepsilon)^{n+1} + \frac{n}{(n+1)(2-\varepsilon)}(1 - (1-\varepsilon)^{n+1}) \to \frac{1}{2-\varepsilon}.$$ Since $\varepsilon > 0$ was arbitrary, we can conclude by squeeze theorem that $nI_n \to \frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume your limit exists. From your recursion formula,
$I_n + I_{n-1} = 1/n$. Since $I_n>0$ for all $n$, this in particular implies that $I_n \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Multiplying the above by $n$ we get
$$nI_n + (n-1)I_{n-1} + I_{n-1} = 1$$
and letting $n\to\infty$ yields $2L = 1$, hence $L = 1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=\sqrt{t}$, then
$$I_n=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^n}{x+1} dx=\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{1} \frac{t^{n/2-1/2} dt}{1+\sqrt{t}}$$
Note that $$\frac{t^{n/2-1/2}}{1+\sqrt{t}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1-t^{n/2}}{1-t} -\frac{1-t^{n/2-1/2}}{1-t}\right)$$
By the definition of Harmonic Numbers
$$H_m=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1-z^m}{1-z} dz$$
So we get $$I_n=\frac{1}{2} [H_{n/2}-H_{n/2-1/2}]$$
Further as $$H_m\sim \gamma+\ln m+\frac{1}{2m}+O(1/m^2)$$
Then $$I_n\sim -\frac{1}{2} \ln(1-1/n) \sim \frac{1}{2n}$$
Eventually,
$$L=\lim_{n\to \infty} n\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^n}{x+1} dx=\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score -1):

Given that
$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{x^n}{x+1}=0$, except for $x=1$,
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} n\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^n}{x+1} dx=\lim_{n\to \infty}n\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^n}{1+1} dx=\frac12
$$

Comment: This is not correct.